# Retrieve data from many to many table in hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, many-to-many

I have a many to many relationship between users and adverts which is mapped like this

```
    @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinTable(name = "faved_ads",
           joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "advert_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
           inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
public List<User> getFavouriters() {
    return favouriters;
}


    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "favouriters")
public List<Advert> getFavourites() {
    return favourites;
}
```

How do I retrieve this data back from the database if I was wanting to find all the ads a certain user had favourited?  Can it be done through creating criteria restrictions or projections?

This is how i've retrieved data from a one to many but can't get a similar solution for many to many

```
    public static <T> List<T> getList(Criteria criteria) {
    List<T> results = null;
    try {
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        results = criteria.list();
        transaction.commit();
    } catch (HibernateException ex) {
        transaction.rollback();
        ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        session.close();
    }
    return results;
}

    public static List<Advert> usersAdverts(User user) {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Advert.class);
    cr.createAlias("user", "user");
    cr.add(Restrictions.eq("user.id", user.getId()));
    return getList(cr);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: `public List<Advert> getFavourites() { ... }` - is it within `User` class?

Comment: yes that's correct

Comment: cool! Than see my answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that you don't need any criteria *to find all the ads a certain user had favourited*. It is simply:

```
public static List<Advert> usersAdverts(User user) {
    Hibernate.initialize(user.getFavourites());
    return user.getFavourites(); 
}
```

However, if the `user` object is detached from the session - then open a new transaction, re-read the object and initialize its collection as I offered above (before detaching `user` from the session!).

:-)

Comment: unfortunately that doesn't work due to LazyInitializationException.  If you were to make the fetch type eager then you get an error along the lines of unable to retrieve multiple bags

Comment: See my update in the question. Basically you need to initialize your collection

Comment: I am glad to help you

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else with this issue, the above solution worked when just querying the database, however to avoid the 'Hibernate collection is not associated with any session' error when using the function with Spark/Velocity I had to add the following into the code:

```
    public static List<Advert> usersFavAdverts(User user) {
    session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    session.refresh(user);
    Hibernate.initialize(user.getFavourites());
    return user.getFavourites();
}
```